# why cant i activate theme in wordpress after uploading?

Tags: wordpress

i am trying to create new ecommerce site in my PC (localhost using xampp), fresh wordpress 4.9.1 and fresh database.. all are ok if i activate the default themes like twentyseventeen or twentysixteen, but when i upload new theme, all theme including the new uploaded theme are unable to activate, i always get this error

> This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this
>   request. HTTP ERROR 500

this is the first time i encounter this kind of problem, anyone can help me please? thanks

Comment: Maybe permissions issue

Comment: Just copy your theme, into your projects/wp-content/themes instead of uploading it from Theme Menu, and then try to activate. Hope that will works.

Comment: i did, but still cant activate any themes.. i still got the error error message

Answer (score 0):

I would check the php.ini file and have a look at how much memory is allocated as twentysixteen and twentyseventeen are fairly small themes not consuming much memory, dependent on the size of the theme you're using you may need to up the memory.

Open up 'wp-config.php' file in a text editor and there will be a line saying `'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M'` increase that from the default of 64M to 128M and see if you run the same issues.

Comment: i add this code define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M'); to wp-config.php but still i got the error.